# windows command for grand total

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a easy way to calculate the grand total of all the numberic values specified line by line using a windows command (or batch file - least prefer)

suppose

```
7612
7724
19844
20092
20184
20468
27100
36456
39428
54264
69008
97208
```

assume this is in a file

I want the total of all the values. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any command line utility to compute such a sum. But you can use a for loop iterating through the file. Something like this will work but you will need a helper batch file. In Sum.bat dump:

```
REM. Turn off echo-ing of individual commands
@echo off

REM. Set variable a to 0. /a mean arithmetic expression
set /a sum = 0

REM. For loop updating the sum as we go
FOR /F %%i IN (file.txt) DO set /a sum += %%i

REM. Output
echo %sum%
```